# How can I store all states of a component in one array and then pass it to parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

1. So, I have one component that contains multiple sub-components with different react states. Like title, keywords, location, date and so on
2. How can I store all states in one array (info)? Each element of this array should be an object
3. After I store it, I need to pass it to parent component.

```
const CreateEventsBasic = () => {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);
  return (
    <div className="create-event-basic">
      <BasicInfo/>
      <Keywords />
      <Location />
      <Date />
      <LinkToTheGroup />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: In React, data flows in downward direction, not the other way around.

What you can do is have the state in the parent component and pass that state, as props, down to each child component.

Comment: I would recommend having a look at a global store, like Redux. This can help you out. Otherwise, if you want to use local state, you will have to pass a function that updates the ```CreateEventsBasic``` down to children and call it when the state changes. Instead of having an array, it would be better to use an object instead

Comment: @szczocik i'm not that good at english, but it's meant to be an array of objects. And as far as I know you can't pass object in useState directly. But thanks anyway, I'll look out in this direction

Comment: You can do this using Context API too. It's used to have common data store which be used by any child component at any level. It's easy to learn and get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to pass the function down to a child component, and call that function, whenever the child state is being updated. Something like this perhaps.

```
const CreateEventsBasic = () => {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({});
  const updateState = (newState, type) => {
    setInfo({...info, [type]: newState })
  }

  return (
    <div className="create-event-basic">
      <BasicInfo updateState={updateState} />
      <Keywords updateState={updateState} />
      <Location updateState={updateState} />
      <Date updateState={updateState} />
      <LinkToTheGroup updateState={updateState} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then in you child component call it when the state is changed

```
const BasicInfo = ({ updateState }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
     updateState(state, "basicInfo);
  }, [state])

  return (
    <div></div>
  )
}
```

So on change of the child state, which is tracked with `useEffect`, you call the `updateState` function that was passed as prop. This in turn adds a child state to the object you have in the parent component.

Comment: Well it's sort of working. But each time state is updated it also stores previous versions of this state as well https://imgur.com/a/J5HBvZw

Comment: That's why I was suggesting to use an object of objects, instead of array of objects. That way you would be able to easily swap old state with new one. Let me update the answer to use the object instead

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed!